# Adding images to Core Data takes a long time

Tags: ios, core-data

How can I make the way I add images to the core data more efficient?

Comment: Start with a "placeholder" image. Use a background-thread download process. As each image download completes, update the UI and save the image data.

Comment: Also, don't store binary data in Core Data. Store your images on disk and store the _paths_ in Core Data.

Comment: is this whats slowing it down?

Comment: Don't [delete and repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399542/efficient-way-to-add-images-to-core-data-objective-c). You'll get yourself banned.

Comment: This line:  `NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: str] options:0 error:&error];` is what's "slowing it down". Each time that line executes in your loop, it sits there and waits for the file data to download. Depending on image sizes and connection speeds, etc, that could take many seconds (or even minutes) per image. Start by searching on `ios sdk async download`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a pretty bad idea to save "Data" or Image here in core data persistance. Also i think you are running this code in the background queue, if not then thats also a bad thing. But then again, saving the image or data into core data persistant store is a very bad idea and should be avoided whenever you can.

As an alternate you can do this -

1. Save the image in the local directory with a path and a unique
   filename.
2. Save the filename in core data except the path.
3. Next time when you retrieve the image, get the filename from the Data store.
4. Append the filename with the whole path untill the folder. Retrieve the image.

This is a much more efficient and better way to store images.

Comment: I currently have the image stored as binary data, and its like that in the actual mysql database, is this whats slowing it down?

Comment: It probably is and is a very bad practice, it will slow down the app and probably later on as the app deals with more and more image, problems will start compounding. Change the architecture is the best solution I can give you.

Comment: This was my answer which you deleted instead of accepting. That's not very considerate at all.